# HTTP(S) request to another server using Java tools?

Tags: java, http, https

I'm new to this and I need my Java program to send http or https requests on the different websites(for example, Amazon)

so it can get the HTML code and than I would be able to find information(price on some goods) that I need via Pattern class.
Did anybody faced with that task? Maybe you used JSON or other tools? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Amazon have an [API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/). You should using instead of trying to parse their website.

Regarding libs to call webservices in JAVA, you could use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: @KirillLukenyuk I don't know what you mean by AWS. I've updated the api with a working one.

Comment: @user2641570 AWS is Amazon Web Services... since you mentioned Amazon as an example, it was unclear whether you were referring to the company's website or an API that is hosted on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts to what you are asking:

1. Constructing / determining what to include in the HTTP request
2. Issuing the actual HTTP request
3. Parsing the response

The first and last are dependent on the particular service / API you are invoking, though if the API response is in a standard format (e.g. JSON), there are libraries that can help you interpret the response (though exactly which fields in the response mean something to you, will depend on the particular API and your application). Issuing the HTTP request, itself, is something that can be done with a number of different libraries, including the builtin [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) / [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) classes, as well as third party libraries such as the [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) or the [Google HTTP Java Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client), the latter of which includes libraries for parsing common output formats, as well.

Comment: but will I retrieve an html code to the String variable? Or how would this suppose to be?

Comment: You haven't clearly specified what API you are invoking. Most APIs, though, return data in a more structured format like JSON. For parsing HTML responses, check out jsoup: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: I honestly don't know. I just want my Java program go to the Internet on the specified page and get the html code. Than I will find required information inside this code via Strings. That's it. What I'm asking is that is it possible? Or it works in a different way? Maybe there are some good articles online?

Comment: The way your Java program "go[es] to the Internet" is by issuing HTTP requests (via a library like ones described). You get back an HTTP response, which contains the HTML content, which you can then parse with an HTML library. I'd suggest reading up on HTTP and HTML / DOM. HTML pages are primarily intended for human consumption, though... if there is an API available (for programs to invoke), that is generally better to use. The process is similar, but then the string parsing is easier / faster and also much more stable/reliable.

Comment: Ok, I send an HTTP request to some facebook page, for example. but where should i place this HTML content? I mean, I tried to put it in String but the size is obviously too small for the html document.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're probably going to have a difficult time if you're accessing Facebook, though, since that requires authentication. Walk before you run... I'd suggest playing around with some examples that are publicly accessible, first.

Comment: Michael, I dont mean it has to be facebook or any other kind of a social network. Ok, I'll explain you my problem one more time. Trust me you will understand it. My Java program sends and HTTP requests on a different websites. What is the result of the HTTP request? - HTML document. So my question is - where is this HTML document is going to be placed? Another words, where should I put it in?

Comment: The result of an HTTP request is an HTTP response, and it can contain anything. The type is indicated in the "Content-Type" response header. Often it is "text/html" (HTML) for ordinary web pages, but it is commonly "application/json" (JSON) for endpoints intended to be consumed by programs, and to a lesser extend "application/xml" or "text/xml" for XML responses. But there can be other types, too. This is where knowing what specific website / API you have in mind is important.

Comment: As to where to "put" the response, it really depends on what you are planning on doing with it. While you are processing it, you can just have it in a String in memory (though you will probably end up using a "parser" to convert it to a hierarchy of objects that is easier to understand), but what you do with the parsed output (extract some data and save it to a file or write it to a database), depends on your particular application.

Comment: maybe it has to be a txt document and than i could parse it to find information that i need. For example, if I'm searching vehicle website I want to put whole HTML document into a file.txt and than find a tank capacity.

Comment: that is what needed to understand. Thank you very much, Michael